# AngularJS autocomplete visual studio code

Tags: angularjs, intellisense, visual-studio-code

Estou criando uma API para angularjs e sei que no vs code você pode escrever um aquivo de d.ts que define os tipos e outras coisas na IDE.
Já criei este aquivo index.d.ts para o autocomplete e funcionou para variáveis globais e etc.

**Código que define os tipos do meu serviço**

```
declare var $ticket: sgtalk.$ticket;

export as namespace $ticket;

export = $ticket;

declare namespace sgtalk {
    interface $ticket {
        /**
         * @returns {string} Tipo
         */
        getSimpleList(): Object;

        /**
         * @param {number} display O número que descreve o ticket
         */
        getTicketData(display: number): Object;

        // answer()

        // senTicketData()
    }
}
```

**Demostrando como fica o intellisense**
[image: demostração]

O problema é que quando eu coloco este mesmo nome no Inject do angular ele não detecta o que é.

e.g:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dei uma rápida pesquisada na internet mas não encontrei nada que pudesse me ajudar.

Comment: Jovem. Angular2 é **completamente diferente** de AngularJS. Você está usando Angular2 ou AngularJS com TypeScript?

Comment: AngularJS com JS normal, porém no vscode, quando você tem o arquivo jsconfig e o arquivo de definição(.d.ts) você pode utilizar o autocomplete e intellisense